# Cross Site Scripting Poor Validation ESAPI + JSF Fortify

Tags: xss, fortify, esapi

i would like to encode the value attribute using the ESAPI library using the  specific method: ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTMLAttribute(). My question is should i be using this method in the JSF itself or in the MessageBean? If i were to encode this in the JSF is this the correct syntax?

```
<h3></f:verbatim><h:outputText id="frsubject" value="#{MessageBean.frSubject}" /><f:verbatim></h3>

<h3></f:verbatim><h:outputText id="frsubject" value=<%= ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTMLAttribute("#{MessageBean.frSubject}") %> /><f:verbatim></h3>
```

Thansk @BalusC. Sorry for the late response i was also under the impression that with  i would be safe from xss attacks(using JSF 1.2). However in the fortify report the explanation is as below:

The use of certain encoding constructs, such as the  tag with the escapeXml="true" attribute (the default behavior), will
prevent some, but not all cross-site scripting attacks. Depending on the context in which the data appear, characters beyond the
basic <, >, &, and " that are HTML-encoded and those beyond <, >, &, ", and ' that are XML-encoded may take on metameaning.
Relying on such encoding constructs is equivalent to using a weak blacklist to prevent cross-site scripting and might
allow an attacker to inject malicious code that will be executed in the browser. Because accurately identifying the context in
which the data appear statically is not always possible, Fortify Static Code Analyzer reports cross-site scripting findings even
when encoding is applied and presents them as Cross-Site Scripting: Poor Validation issues.

Comment: Are you using jsf-1.2?

Comment: This question is strange. JSF has already builtin XSS prevention since version 1.0. In JSF 1.x you only have to use `<h:outputText>`. In JSF 2.x you only have to use Facelets instead of JSP. Probably you're looking at the wrong places for XSS holes? These `<h:outputText>` tags should already escape XSS for you. Or you have overridden the default renderer of the `HtmlOutputText` component in a bad way. In any case, JSP is deprecated since JSF 2.0 (2009). Catch up.

Comment: @BalusC according to the documentation the only thing escaped by ‘outputtext’ is angle brackets!

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/outputText.html

Comment: Nope, it says *"Flag indicating that characters that are sensitive in HTML and XML markup must be escaped. This flag is set to "true" by default."*. You can also confirm it by looking at the source code. Moreover, JSF exist for 14 years already and there's only one CVE security bug been reported which was already more than a decade ago fixed in the prehistoric Mojarra 1.2_08 version. That ESAPI thing is only useful for JSP even though it has via JSTL already `<c:out>` and `${fn:escapeXml()}` at hands for the very purpose of HTML escaping.